# How to remove documents from embedded where name is.. and start is greater than...?

Tags: mongodb, embedded-documents

I'm trying to remove some embedded documents from history. I'm using mongodb 3.2
There are two conditions:

1. "name" must be for example sa
2. "history" "start" must be greater some date

```
{
    "name" : "sa",
    "history" : [ 
        {
            "start" : ISODate("2015-11-11T12:46:32.000Z"),
            "value" : "color1"
        }, 
        {
            "start" : ISODate("2015-11-12T11:54:20.000Z"),
            "value" : "color2"
    }]
}
{
    "name" : "sa",
    "history" : [ 
        {
            "start" : ISODate("2015-11-11T12:46:32.000Z"),
            "value" : "color1"
        }, 
        ]
            "start" : ISODate("2015-11-12T11:54:20.000Z"),
            "value" : "color2"
    }] 
}
{
    "name" : "so",
    "history" : [ 
        {
            "start" : ISODate("2015-11-11T12:46:32.000Z"),
            "value" : "color1"
        }, 
        {
            "start" : ISODate("2015-11-12T11:54:20.000Z"),
            "value" : "color2"
    }] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't do it directly. I download the collection and then do the operations that I need, remove the old collection and then insert the new collection with the data that I need.